# Lightning VisualForce Component theme

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I have the following VisualForce Lightning component:

```
<apex:page standardStyleSheets="false" standardController="Case" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <apex:slds />
</head>
<body>
<div class="slds-scope">

<button class="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-top--medium" type="button" onClick="window.open('https://my-company.com/{!Case.Contact.Email}/devices','_blank')">My Devices</button>

<button class="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-top--medium" type="button" onClick="window.open('https://my-company.com/{!Case.Contact.Email}&commit=Search','_blank')">User Emails</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

The outcome is as follows: 
[image]

How can I match the background color? I tried using '[theme](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/themes/)', but this only added the background within in internal panel.

Comment: Not sure if I can help, but have you tried to check the theme just in case that VF is not able to read it. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2016/04/introducing-ui-theme-detection-for-lightning-experience.html

Comment: @iDog : The easiest way would be to use the mark-up from Cards section. The example that you have shown , seems to be using cards , so in your VF page, you can try implementing the cards from SLDS library.

Reference : https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/#react-target

This would give you the grey backgound what you are expecting.